# jQuery events not bind to page items after $.load()

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I have a base index page and a large repository page which I load needed elements from it with `jquery.load()` function for the sake of cleaner code and less size. After I load some parts in the base page for example some buttons, all the event handlers which I added to new loaded page items in a js file wont work.
Here is my sample code from js file:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var tData = $(this).text();
    console.log(tData)
})
```

Can anybody help?
Maybe I am wrong in placing all my html code in one place except creating them on the fly,
or I should add a script tag after each part of my html?

Comment: Try with `$('body')` instead of `$(document.body)`

Comment: Are you using a jQuery version older then 1.7? If so: use live() instead of on()

Comment: @sdespont jQuery normalizes `document.body` across all browsers ;)

Comment: hmm I don't understand. Are you saying the above code doesn't work, or after you add some HTML with jquery the event isn't triggered on click on the new HTML?

Comment: every body so sorry the answer on the bottom is right and its my dumbness or may be tiredness. that is so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrap your code in the ready method once the jquery js file has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', '.btn', function(){
       var tData = $(this).text();
       console.log(tData)
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, so dumb i am. i feel so stupid! completely forgot the simplest part :D